# Table view is updating randomly on scrolling with scroll bar

Tags: javafx

I have a problem in which the `TableView` rows are getting updated with redundant data while scrolling the `scrollbar`. To explain you in detail, i have a `TableView` in which each cell is having a `TextField` and `ComboBox` on the `TextField`. Now, when i write the data into the `cell`, everything works fine with `startEdit`, `updateItem`, `commitEdit` are working fine. Now, when i start scrolling the `TableView` towards down side, the data in the upper rows gets updated in to the downside rows also without performing any action except scrolling. Find the code below which helps you to understand it better.

This is my `FXML` File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
    <AnchorPane fx:id="mainPanelFromTestCaseEditor" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="415.0" prefWidth="171.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.TestCaseEditorController">
       <children>
          <AnchorPane fx:id="subPanelFromTestCaseEditor" layoutY="-14.0" prefHeight="415.0" prefWidth="458.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
          <TableView fx:id="testCaseEditorTableView" prefHeight="415.0" prefWidth="458.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <columns>
              <TableColumn fx:id="actionColumnFromtestCaseEditorTable" maxWidth="170.1999877691269" minWidth="99.99999845027924" prefWidth="148.79999387264252" sortable="false" text="Action" />
            </columns>
             <columnResizePolicy>
                <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
             </columnResizePolicy>
          </TableView>
       </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

Below is the Main Method:

```
package com;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public  class MainClass extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
    {
        Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(MainClass.class.getResource("TestCaseEditorView.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Resynchronize Merge Window-TestcaseId");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root,600,400));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Below is my controller class:

```
package com;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.util.Callback;
public class TestCaseEditorController  implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane mainPanelFromTestCaseEditor;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane subPanelFromTestCaseEditor;
    @FXML
    public      TableView<TestCaseFormid> testCaseEditorTableView;
    @FXML
    public  TableColumn<TestCaseFormid,String> actionColumnFromtestCaseEditorTable;

    public static TableView<TestCaseFormid> testCaseEditorTableView1;
    public   static TableColumn<TestCaseFormid,String> actionColumnFromtestCaseEditorTable1;
    public static ObservableList<TestCaseFormid> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) 
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
        testCaseEditorTableView1 = testCaseEditorTableView;
        actionColumnFromtestCaseEditorTable1=actionColumnFromtestCaseEditorTable;
        
        testCaseEditorTableContentPreparation();
        //additionalRemarksColumnFromtestCaseEditorTable.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TestCaseFormid, String>("additionalRemark"));
        actionColumnFromtestCaseEditorTable1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TestCaseFormid, String>("action"));
                Callback<TableColumn<TestCaseFormid, String>, TableCell<TestCaseFormid, String>> actioncellFactory = (TableColumn<TestCaseFormid, String> p) -> new  ActionCellEditor();
                actionColumnFromtestCaseEditorTable.setCellFactory(actioncellFactory);
                testCaseEditorTableView1.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
                testCaseEditorTableView1.setEditable(true);
                testCaseEditorTableView1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
                testCaseEditorTableView1.setSnapToPixel(false);
                testCaseEditorTableView1.setStyle("-fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;");
    
    }
    ///containt preparation----------------------------------
    public void testCaseEditorTableContentPreparation()
    {
        /**Intiate object of table model**/
        TestCaseFormid testCaseTablePojo = null;
        /**Create a loop with some length and prepare content to add that into table model**/
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            /**Add content into table model properties**/
            if(i==0 )
            {
                TestCaseFormid preHeader = new TestCaseFormid("Pre steps");
                list.add(preHeader);
                for(int j=1;j<=9;j++) {
                    TestCaseFormid c1 = new TestCaseFormid("");
                    list.add(c1);
                }
            }
            else if(i==1)
            {
                TestCaseFormid testHeader = new TestCaseFormid("Test Steps");
                list.add(testHeader);
                for(int k=1;k<=9;k++)
                {
                    TestCaseFormid c1 = new TestCaseFormid("");
                    list.add(c1);
                }
            }
            else if(i==2)
            {
                TestCaseFormid postHeader = new TestCaseFormid("Post Steps");
                list.add(postHeader);
                for(int p=1;p<=9;p++)
                {
                    TestCaseFormid c1 = new TestCaseFormid("");
                    list.add(c1);
                }
            }
            testCaseEditorTableView1.setItems(list);
            //tableview.getItems().addAll(testCaseTablePojo);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my Object Class

```
package com;
public class TestCaseFormid 
{​​​​​​​
    private String action = null;
    public TestCaseFormid (String action) {​​​​​​​
        this.action = action;
       // this.isHeader=isHeader;
    }​​​​​​​
    public String getAction() {​​​​​​​
        return action;
    }​​​​​​​
    public void setAction(String action) {​​​​​​​
        this.action = action;
    }​​​​​​​
}​​​​​​​
```

Below is my cell editor class:

```
package com;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class ActionCellEditor extends TableCell<TestCaseFormid, String> 
{
    public TableView<TestCaseFormid> table;
    private ComboBox<String> actioncomboBox;
    private TextField textField;

    //TextField editor1 = (TextField) actioncomboBox.getEditor();
    List<TestCaseFormid> list = new LinkedList<>();

    boolean keyPressed = false;
    boolean isEscape   = false;
    String         preText = "";
    String         key     = null;
    int caretPos = -1;

    public ActionCellEditor()
    {
        this.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> this.handleCellMouseClick(mouseEvent));

    }
    @Override
    public void startEdit() 
    {

        super.startEdit();
        if (actioncomboBox == null) 
        {
            if (isEditable()) 
            {
                createTextField(); 

            } else 
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        setGraphic(actioncomboBox);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {

                actioncomboBox.requestFocus();
                actioncomboBox.getEditor().selectAll();

            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit()
    {

        super.cancelEdit();

        if (getItem() != null) {
            setText(String.valueOf(getItem()));
        }

        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);

    }
    @Override
    public void commitEdit( final String valNew) {
        if (isEditing()) 
        {

            super.commitEdit(valNew);
        } 
        else 
        {
            final TableView<TestCaseFormid> tbl = getTableView();
            if (tbl != null) 
            {
                final TablePosition<TestCaseFormid, String> pos = new TablePosition<>(tbl, getTableRow().getIndex(), getTableColumn()); // instead of tbl.getEditingCell()
                final CellEditEvent<TestCaseFormid, String> ev = new CellEditEvent<>(tbl, pos, TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), valNew);
                Event.fireEvent(getTableColumn(), ev);

            }
            updateItem(valNew, false);
            if (tbl != null) 
            {
                tbl.edit(-1, null);
            }

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) 
        {
            this.setText(null);
            this.setGraphic(null);
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (isEditing()) 
            {

            }
            else
            {
                setText(String.valueOf(getItem()));
                //setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                setEditable(true);
            }
        }
    }
    private  void createTextField() 
    {
        actioncomboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
        actioncomboBox.setEditable(true);
        actioncomboBox.getItems().addAll("A", "B", "C");
        actioncomboBox.setMinHeight(17.0);
        actioncomboBox.setPrefHeight(actioncomboBox.getMinHeight());
        TextField editor = (TextField) actioncomboBox.getEditor();
        editor.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
        setGraphic(textField);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);

        editor.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) ->
        {
            if (isNowFocused) 
            {
                commitEdit(editor.getText());
            }
        });
        editor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {

            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) 
            {
                //editor.focusedProperty().removeListener(changeListener);
                cancelEdit();
            }
            else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) 
            {
                commitEdit(sanitizeInput(editor.getText()));
                cancelEdit();
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectRightCell();
                event.consume();
            } 
            else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) 
            {
                commitEdit(sanitizeInput(editor.getText()));
                cancelEdit();
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectLeftCell();
                event.consume();
            } 
            else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP)
            {
                commitEdit(editor.getText());
                cancelEdit();
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectAboveCell();
                event.consume();
            }
            else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) 
            {
                commitEdit(sanitizeInput(editor.getText()));
                cancelEdit();
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell();
                event.consume();
            }
            else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) 
            {
                commitEdit(editor.getText());
                cancelEdit();
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        editor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event -> 
        {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) 
            {
                System.out.println("exc");

                cancelEdit();
                event.consume();
            }

            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    commitEdit(editor.getText());
                    cancelEdit();
                    event.consume();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void handleCellMouseClick(final MouseEvent mouseEvent)
    {
        TablePosition pos = TestCaseEditorController.testCaseEditorTableView1.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        TableCell<Map<String, String>, String> cell = (TableCell<Map<String, String>, String>) mouseEvent.getSource();
        int index = cell.getIndex();

        cell.setOnMouseClicked(Event  ->
        {
            if (mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY))
            {

                if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 1)
                {
                    TestCaseEditorController.testCaseEditorTableView1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> 
                    {
                        if (newSelection != null) 
                        {
                            int row = TestCaseEditorController.testCaseEditorTableView1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getRow();
                            Platform.runLater(() -> TestCaseEditorController.testCaseEditorTableView1.edit(row, TestCaseEditorController.actionColumnFromtestCaseEditorTable1));
                            cancelEdit();
                            mouseEvent.consume();

                        }
                    });


                }

            }
        });
    }
    private String sanitizeInput(String string) {

        if (string != null && !string.isEmpty()) {
            return string;
        }
        return "";
    }
    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem();
    }
}
```

The below screen shots will help u to understand more about my problem:
[Before scrolling, no redundant is found in the downside rows...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbPSc.png)

[After scrolling, redundant is found in the downside rows...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pSnL.png)

Comment: [mcve] please ... mind the __M__!

Comment: ohh .. and needing anything _as soon as possible_ is of no relevance here (simply start earlier to not get into time trouble ;), so removed it.

Comment: What's the point of `if (editingIndex!=-1 && selectedRow == editingIndex)`? Placing that code in `updateItem` seems strange to me. It also means you don't call `super.updateItem` unconditionally and it can prevent you from clearing the text and graphic when the cell is empty (thus your artifacts).

Comment: @kleopatra, Thanks for the response!! Added complete code(4 class files)  with which the issue can be easily replicable.

Comment: good starter :) But still far from minimal - restrict your cell to implement just the part that's causing the problem (no reason for all the keyboard navigation stuff, f.i.)

Comment: You have many points where you call _both_ `commitEdit` and `cancelEdit`. You also have fields in your cell class that don't appear to be used anywhere. It's not clear to me how the `ComboBox` relates to the editing of your model. And you're relying on public, static state which makes it hard to follow some things. Ultimately the issue you specifically ask about is caused by not clearing the cell of text and/or graphics when its empty. But with everything going on it's hard to debug that problem. Perhaps if you explained more about what you're trying to create here we could be of more help.

Comment: Along with that explanation, it would be easier to understand your question if you follow @kleopatra advice and make the example more minimal. Unless FXML is strictly necessary you don't need that. As far as I can tell, all you need to reproduce the problem is a `TableView`, your custom `TableCell`, and the model class (and the `Application` class). Also, to make things simpler, you can just use the `TableView` as the root of the `Scene`.